# Qual a principal diferença entre os métodos Thread.Abort e Thread.Finalize?

Tags: c#, thread

Comecei a trabalhar com threads recentemente e me deparei com a necessidade de encerrar uma thread, eliminá-la por completo. Após algumas pesquisas descobri os métodos Abort e Finalize, contudo não entendi qual a principal diferença entre ambos, e quais fatores determinam qual destes utilizar.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Note que Finalize não é um método público.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thread.Abort:**

> Gera um ThreadAbortException no thread no qual ele é invocado, para
>   iniciar o processo de encerramento do thread. Geralmente, a chamada a
>   esse método termina o thread.

Ou seja, o **Thread.abort** interrompe o processo da thread a qualquer momento, de forma assíncrona, em qualquer ponto da aplicação. Porém não é uma boa prática utilizar o método, **geralmente apenas no processo de encerrar o programa**, pois acaba deixando processos em acaba deixando processos em aberto.

**Thread.Finalize**

> Garante que os recursos são liberados e outras operações de limpeza são executadas quando o coletor de lixo recupera o objeto Thread.

Metódo que o garbage collector chama **quando o objeto está pronto para ser finalizado**.

Ou seja, a diferença é que o Abort interrompe a Thread no exato momento da execução, podendo deixar recursos em aberto, enquanto o Finalize espera o garbage collector entender que o objeto está sendo finalizado, sendo relativamente mais seguro, porém ainda há ressalvas.